# Ubuntu 14.10 stuck at blinking cursor

Tags: boot

Hi guys I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 14.10 and after ubuntu is booted it stucks at blinking cursor and there is no login option, just black screen with blinking cursor.

I tryed installing gdm, it didn't help.

Also while booting I got error "saned disabled; edit etc/default/saned" , so I am not sure is it problem or something else.

Also I tryed doing this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226708&page=3&p=13036073#post13036073
and changing boot settings in grub but it didn't help.

At this moment I am reading other topics for help but if someone had some idea that would help.

Comment: `saned` is very certainly not the reason for the issue - it's a scanner managment service and installed in disabled mode by default. Try installing missing drivers with `sudo dkms autoinstall`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following in recovery mode with network, worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg
```

***if you have another video card you need to replace xserver-xorg-video-ati with one of these :***

xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
xserver-xorg-video-intel
xserver-xorg-video-sis